# Import osm data in Docker postgresql

Tags: postgresql, docker, openstreetmap

i am trying to use Docker. So i installed in Docker postgresql image.

Until now, when i imported osm data into postql i used this command:

```
psql -U postgres mydb

 CREATE EXTENSION postgis;

osm2pgsql -U postgres -d mydb -s -S ./osm_stylesheet /home/ramnikov/Downloads/hessen-latest.osm
```

How can i do the same inside Docker after this command

```
$ sudo docker exec -it postgresql sudo -u postgres psql
```

or before this command ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can execute `osm2pgsql` outside of Docker:

> -H|--host        Database server host name or socket location.

As well as `psql`:

> -h, --host=HOSTNAME      database server host or socket directory

Like this:

```
psql -h dockerIP -U postgres -d mydb -c 'create extension postgis'

osm2pgsql -H dockerIP -U postgres -d mydb -s -S ./osm_stylesheet /home/ramnikov/Downloads/hessen-latest.osm
```

Comment: tnx for the fest answer. Every time i running your command i get this error: osm2pgsql SVN version 0.85.0 (64bit id space)

Error: Connection to database failed: could not translate host name "66864b18bb58" to address: Name or service not known

Comment: Hi Stas, i changed it like u showed but steel the same error coming back.

Comment: What do you write in place of `dockerIP`? There should be an IP-address of machine which is within your docker image.